# Extract web data from a long web URL (250+ characters) without using URL shortnener

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking to extract web data from URLs that are over the set 250 character limit on MS Excel 2016. I am using parameters on the URL since the dates and time on URL do change as I would require live values when I refresh link. Using URL shortnener eliminates parameters such as =(["Date",""]) hence why I can not use them as of now.

Any idea as to how I can go about extracting data from an over the limit URL into excel? Many thanks.

Comment: You could use a local proxy like Fiddler[Classic] or Charles or similar and rewrite the URL. Then you could perform a request to e.g. `http://example.test` and internally in the proxy the request would be changed to the long URL.

Comment: I have just downloaded Fiddler. I know I am asking a lot, any way you can illustrate or explain where to input and edit url? @Robert. Thank you

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/redirecting-with-autoresponder